# What is the best practice for storing newlines in text in database?

Tags: html, database, text

The data is displayed as HTML, but I don't want to store `<br />` in database.

Is `\n` the best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not store them as `\n` and do a replace when you query the database to whatever character or character (or even `<br />`) that you want?

Comment: That was the first idea. But sometimes it is not immediately obvious that a `\n` is stored in the database. It depends on how the data is viewed. Also, if the replace does not occur, it looks ugly.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I find that `\r\n` tends to work better.

Comment: I've just found that the addition of a carriage return tends to work more reliably. I don't have any good examples off the top of my head, but I've never had a problem with the above solution.